# RDP connection by making it .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop, batch, batch-file

I want to automate the RDP connection by making a bat file. But it still keeps on asking me the password.

I created two files
1.hello.cmd 
2.hello1.bat

In hello.cmd I had put

```
cmdkey /generic:"ipaddress" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
rem cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV:"ipaddress" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
```

and in hello1.bat I created

```
mstsc /v:ipaddress
```

How do i correct this and make it automate

**Please help!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was removed from the `mstsc.exe` application.
I think you may do either of:

- Save from RDP the connection details as an `.rdp` file and launch it directly
  or via `mstsc`.
- Use PowerShell, for example the script
  [Connect-Mstsc.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b).
  You will find some more information on
  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109820/how-to-infer-powershell-enter-pssession-arguments-from-an-rdp-file),
  google for details on individual commands.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. I am a complete noob of using Powershell. Can you tell me how do I run the Connect-Mstsc.ps1?

Comment: The script is well documented. Search in it for examples, all headed by ".EXAMPLE" and followed by explanations in "Description". The parameters are defined first, each under ".PARAMETER". Pick your example and use it either from the PowerShell IDE or if your prefer from batch via the command `powershell -Command "command-line-with-params"`. Google for information - there's lots of.